# Conversion from string "" to long is not valid

Tags: vb.net, concatenation

I'm getting an error which i can't solve, even after about an hour of research.

> Conversion from String "Waseem-PC\Waseem" to long is not valid

This error really gets annoying, I tried everything!
I would really appreciate help from you. I would love to give your answers a thumbs up but i have to have a bigger rep.

 Here is my code

```
    Private Sub RichTextBox2_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox2.KeyPress
        If Asc(e.KeyChar) = Keys.Enter Then
            RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text And vbNewLine And RichTextBox2.Text
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and turn Option Strict On, either by placing it at the top of your code file or setting it in the project's properties.  If it were on, you would have instantly seen the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're incorrectly using the **[And](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdbcfyzh%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)** keyword which is used for (from MSDN):

> Perform a logical conjunction on two Boolean expressions, or bitwise conjunction on two numeric expressions.

Instead you want to use `&` to ***concatenate*** the strings...

This will work:

```
 Private Sub RichTextBox2_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles RichTextBox2.KeyPress
    If Asc(e.KeyChar) = Keys.Enter Then
        RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text & vbNewLine & RichTextBox2.Text
    End If
End Sub
```