# Getting error that Conversion from String to Long is Not Valid in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to make an error handler, but am getting an error. With my limited English, I do not know how to explain the details of the problem. I hope it is possible that after you see my code you will understand.

I have looked at this, [[Conversion from string "" to long is not valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14726120/conversion-from-string-to-long-is-not-valid][1]) and think the trouble might be with "&" and "Or", but it may be something different.

My code is below. Note that Date1.text, Date2.text, etc.. is `datetimepicker`.

```
Dim No1, No2, No3 No4 As String
    No1 = Date1.Text
    No2 = Date2.Text
    No3 = Date3.Text
    No4 = Date4.Text
Select Case CmbNumber.Text
    Case "1 (ONE)"
        No2 = "-"
        No3 = "-"
        No4 = "-"
    Case "2 (TWO)"
        No1 = "-"
        No3 = "-"
        No4 = "-"
    Case "3 (THREE)"
        No1 = "-"
        No2 = "-"
        No4 = "-"
    Case "4 (FOUR)"
        No1 = "-"
        No2 = "-"
        No3 = "-"
End Select
    If CmbNumber.Text = "4 (FOUR)" Then
        If No1 Or No2 Or No3 = No4 Then 'ERROR Conversion From String to Long
            MsgBox("Not allowed the same date", MsgBoxStyle.Critical + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "ERROR")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: @sjoy While I felt your edit was quite useful, I think you should have left a *comment* about a "trap" being an "error handler" rather than changing it in the question, and to complete the edit you ought to have formatted the code. (I tried to undo my edit reject, but I can't.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton Helpful information for future editing. (minute later) Now don't quite follow. It looks like my edits were applied.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Nevermind. I found the approvals and get it now.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be aware of what an [operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_%28computer_programming%29) is in computer programming and [Operator Precedence in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw84t893.aspx).

From that, you can determine that the computer sees `No1 Or No2 Or No3 = No4` as `No1 Or No2 Or (No3 = No4)` (items in parentheses, i.e. `()` are evaluated first), which is not what you want.

Instead, you want `No1 = No4 Or No2 = No4 Or No3 = No4`.

Now, when you use `Or` it evaluates every condition, even if it is not mathematically necessary. A new operator, `OrElse`, was introduced which only does the evaluations which are needed, so your code would be more efficient using `No1 = No4 OrElse No2 = No4 OrElse No3 = No4`.

Incidentally, you could shorten your code by only setting the value when necessary:

```
Dim No1 As String = "-"
Dim No2 As String = "-"
Dim No3 As String = "-"
Dim No4 As String = "-"
Select Case CmbNumber.Text
    Case "1 (ONE)"
        No1 = Date1.Text
    Case "2 (TWO)"
        No2 = Date2.Text
    Case "3 (THREE)"
        No3 = Date3.Text
    Case "4 (FOUR)"
        No4 = Date4.Text
End Select
```

Comment: actually I 've tried using OrElse operator but I did not succeed , but in the right hands it can be done.. this is what I was looking for.. this is working..thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

The expression`If No1 Or No2 Or No3 = No4` assumes that `No1` and `No2` are of type `Boolean`. You cannot apply the `Or` operator to something which is not boolean.

Comment: so no answer fro my question.. or maybe you're willing to give an alternative way..